# Guardar imagenes en ruta variable

Tags: laravel

Necesito verificar si un archivo existe en el directorio, en caso que sí exista cambiar el nombre y guardarlo, con mi ruta actual funciona, pero ahora debo utilizarlo en directorios de años diferentes por lo que utilizo una variable para colocar el fin del directorio pero no me funciona el código para ubicarlo:

Código actual:

```
if( Storage::disk('image')->exists($oldFileName.'.'.$extension) )
 {
     Storage::disk('image')->move($oldFileName.'.'.$extension, $newFileName.'.'.$extension);
 }
```

Código nuevo:

```
if( Storage::disk('image')->exists($photo->year.'/'.$oldFileName.'.'.$extension) )
 {
     Storage::disk('image')->move($photo->year.'/'.$oldFileName.'.'.$extension, $newFileName.'.'.$extension);
 }
```

Comment: ¿Qué es lo que no funciona? En principio veo que agregas la variable del directorio en el archivo de origen, pero no en el de destino. Prueba así `Storage::disk('image')->move( $photo->year.'/'.$oldFileName.'.'.$extension, $photo->year.'/'.$newFileName.'.'.$extension);`

Comment: El no haber agragado la variable en el archivo de destino podría ser el problema, porque no me cambia el nombre del archivo, ya reviso.

Comment: Perfecto, era eso... No lo había notado. Muchas gracias!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La solución está acá:

```
Storage::disk('image')->move( $photo->year.'/'.$oldFileName.'.'.$extension, $photo->year.'/'.$newFileName.'.'.$extension);
```

Se había agregado la variable del directorio en el archivo de origen, pero no en el de destino.